# Are iPhones immune to deauth attacks?

Tags: wifi, wireless, iphone, deauth-attack

I was today rumbling a bit with wireless security, and more specific in creating Fake Access-Points to make Wi-Fi users enter their password on a phishing-page (by using the Fluxion tool).

One of the steps require you to deauthenticate the user(s) in order to capture the handshake. When I launched this deauth-attack the Windows-computers and Android-phones connected to that network were indeed disconnected; however my iPhone connected to the same network was not getting affected at all! It's MAC-address was not even shown in the Xterm Fluxion showed. I retried it with different tools but iPhone was never affected.

So, is iPhone somehow 'secured' against deauth attacks?
And why aren't deauth packets authenticated by the Access Point to avoid these deauth attacks are not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, iphone is not secured against this. It is a fundamental flaw in the WiFi protocol that this can happen. You need to be able to deauth clients before they are properly authenticated for other reasons, that is why this has to happen in plain text. Most likely you encountered one of the following ( from the aircrack documentation):

-Wireless cards work in particular modes such b, g, n and so on. If your card is in a different mode then the client card there is good chance that the client will not be able to correctly receive your transmission. See the previous item for confirming the client received the packet.

-Some clients ignore broadcast deauthentications. If this is the case, you will need to send a deauthentication directed at the particular client.

-Clients may reconnect too fast for you to see that they had been disconnected. If you do a full packet capture, you will be able to look for the reassociation packets in the capture to confirm deauthentication worked